# Is Ubuntu 17.10 safe on Lenovo Laptops if it is already installed?

Tags: boot, 17.10, lenovo, bios

I've read recently that Ubuntu 17.10  [can break the BIOS on Lenovo laptops.](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/12/ubuntu-corrupting-lenovo-laptop-bios) I have a Lenovo laptop, and I installed 17.10 on it as soon as it came out.  I haven't had any problems yet, but I would certainly like to avoid them, even if t means installing 17.04 or such.

If Ubuntu 17.10 is already installed on my Lenovo Laptop, am I still at risk for BIOS corruption.  Is there any surefire way of avoiding this, such as disabling a certain update?

Comment: Even if you do not have a Lenovo: don't touch 17.10 and do not update if you have it.

Comment: @Rinzwind I was of the belief that the 17.10 problem was confined to certain versions of Lenovo - is there more information somewhere?

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/12/ubuntu-corrupting-lenovo-laptop-bios

Comment: @CharlesGreen nope. There are also at least 3 Acers and 3 Toshiba lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The launchpad bug website indicates that a fix for Artful (17.10) has been released - see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1734147

The fix is to load kernel => 4.13.0-21.24, which is currently available in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: So what action is needed on my part?  Can I turn on my computer and install all updates without rebooting to avoid this issue.  Would this be a permanent fix?

Comment: Several people in the bug report have mentioned blacklisting the intel spi modules (this is the driver that allows writing to the BIOS - I would think that doing this is probably a good start.  If they really have created a release in 4.13.0-21.24 that prevents the BIOS from being overwritten, then I would apply that upgrade.  I will research that a bit more and update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Because BIOS issues can be permanent.  I want to be absolutely sure that nothing is going to break my laptop.  Is there any official word from Canonical?

Comment: I'm a volunteer here - like most others!  Some good information at [this link](http://linuxiumcomau.blogspot.com/2017/12/lenovo-bios-issues.html)

Comment: [this link](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/artful/main/updates/linux-image-4.13.0-21-generic) indicates that the lernel mentioned is directly aimed at preventing the problem with BIOS.  I assume that this means you really want to install it.

Comment: Is this in the repositories yet?  Could a simple `apt-get upgrade` install it?

Comment: Yes, I got it through a regular upgrade last night

Comment: +1: Thanks for doing this research job for us :-)

Answer (score 0):

No, but STOP updates until it is resolved as that could cause that even thougt it didnt occur yet.

Comment: Do you have a source to read more?

Comment: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/12/ubuntu-corrupting-lenovo-laptop-bios

Comment: @OrganicMarble I think they meant a source to read more on the claim that updates alone can trigger the issue on a current 17.10 install.